# CloudWatchAgent Custom metrics are not being added with SSM parameter store

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I want custom metrics using CloudwatchAgent with Command line.Stored config file in SSM store when i run the cloudwatch agent,it is executing successfully but i dont see any Custom metrics.
Any thoughts?Attached CloudAgentServer and Admin roles to instance.
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to do? Install Cloudwatch agent using SSM run command or automation?

Comment: So i want to create a custom metrics using cloudwatch agent storing config file in SSM parameter store. So while running Cloudwatch agent fetching the config file from parameter store ,it is executing but i dont see any metrics created by CW agent